# How to quickly unlock Dragon of Dojima abilities?

Tags: yakuza-0

I've managed to get max money (10 trillion yen) by losing to Mr. Shakedown and getting 1.5x my money back. Now I'd like to spend my yen on Dragon of Dojima abilities, but it takes over a minute and less than 30 billion yen to unlock the grid once. I should be able to get to level 333 at 30 billion a level, but it would take about 8 hours to do so. Is there any way to speed this process up?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a quick way to upgrade abilities. In fact, you seem to have undersold how long upgrading takes. It took me 3 minutes and 49 seconds to fully upgrade 1 level of Dojima abilities, meaning it would take around 21 hours to reach level 333.

There are a few things you can do to avoid making the process take even longer:

- Navigate with the d-pad instead of the left thumb stick when possible. The d-pad snaps between nodes instead of needing to move the cursor across empty space between nodes.
- When you reach the multi-column abilities, unlock them in straight columns starting with the center (1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 12) followed by the left and right sides.
- After unlocking an ability, you can dismiss the "Ability Acquired" text early by pressing A.